# Can I my iOS-based editor save .plist files that my Mac game can read?

Tags: ios, macos

I want to make an editor on iOS which will record touch positions into a file. That file (in the `.plist` format) will eventually be used for positions in my Mac connect-the-dots game.

Can I save one `.plist` file to my Mac from an iOS app?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is this a game that's played on iOS and a Mac? I don't really get why you'd need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this directly.

You can, however, rely on a standard method of transporting data between machines: the internet. Probably the most straightforward option would be to use either [iCloud storage containers](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php) or [Dropbox's API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). Both APIs provide a way you can save files on one device and access them later from another device.

If you want something more "real-time" you could establish manual socket connections between your editor and game and transfer the data that way (at that point you probably don't want to bother sending a whole `.plist` file, just send the position updates you need).